# Advantages of three tier architecture from the point of view of an end user

Tags: user-interface, architecture

What is the advantages of a three tier architecture from a user's point of view, not from a developer point of view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Nothing!**

Architecture has got nothing to do with the end-user.

Comment: Developer advantages/disadvantages of architectures affect the software and can therefore flow onto the end-user. Software/service downtime/responsiveness/capabilities.

Comment: Try telling this to the business owner. What if your mechanic told you, how he was going to fix your car had nothing to do with you, that your only concern should be that it works?

Answer (score 5):

The only benefit that reaches the user is that new features and bug fixes are completed more quickly, assuming the architecture is actually done correctly. The end user will not, however, care why or how.

Answer (score 1):

You have messed up if the user even gets to know about the layers... we have layers/tiers only for abstraction and separation of concerns

Answer (score 0):

A good architecture also makes software less buggy.